# Unable to get push notifications when .iPA file is generated through diawi and app is installed in device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I'm working on Apple push notification for my app. Here my app is working fine while debugging stage. But when i generate IPA file through diawi and install on my device. Push notification are not working. Device is unable to receive push notification. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: have you generated push certificate for production/ad-hoc?

Comment: yes of course its working fine in debugging stage.......

Comment: make sure you delete app first and then install from diawi... I test from diawi and all works good... `delete app first` is not required, but there might be some issue and this is causing...

Comment: i have tried that for several times but no use.....

Answer (score 0):

You can check out two things into it:

1) Make sure you are using the same provisional profile to create a build.

2) Make sure you have enable all necessary setting for push in xCode project.

3) If you do both of above steps, then try to alert deviceToken which you get in **didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken** method.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSString *dt = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                    [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    dt = [dt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
}
```

You can see [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started) tutorial for more explanation.